# How could I control access to Google Cloud Storage objects using my own auth system?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am currently using Google Cloud Storage to handle storage for my application. While reading the documentation for GCS, I was wondering how could I control who can have access to what when I have my own auth system as opposed to Firebase etc

For example, I have two different roles, **admin** and **user**. A user with the role **user** can upload a file, delete their file but a user cannot see another user's files. An **admin** can see all users' files.

Is this something that is possible with Google Cloud Storage especially when using your own auth system (sessions with redis)?

Couldn't find any clear examples on Google Cloud Storage docs for what I am looking for, would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only access management system for Google Cloud Storage is Google [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). You cannot replace that system.

You can, however, add a layer on top of IAM inside your application. I use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to grant access to users based upon my local authorization system. The users authenticate to my application, request a signed URL, and then directly access Cloud Storage. I use HTTP redirects to transparently request signed URLs. The users see Cloud Storage objects as routes within my application. This might sound complex, but is easy to implement in most frameworks. I use the technique with Laravel for both Google and Azure storage. The actual Cloud Storage requests then happen in the browser coded in JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh, I was reading about Signed URLs and thought I could use them but wasn't sure. My only problem is that apparently the NodeJS client cannot be used to make signed URLs for listing objects in a bucket which is a bit unfortunate but not a big deal. I'll take a deeper dive into this route, thanks.